# O que as linhas de código à seguir fazem?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

Tenho este código:

```
Arvore*   arv_insere   (Arvore* arvore, Registro* registro){  
  if (arvore == NULL){  
    printf(COLOR_RED     "ERROR: Arvore não inicializada"     COLOR_RESET "\n");  
    exit(1);  
  }  

  float direction = reg_compare(arvore->label, registro);  
  if (direction == 0.0){  
    printf(COLOR_RED     "ERROR: Não permitimos chaves repetidas"     COLOR_RESET "\n");  
    exit(1);  
  }  

  bool isTaller; // Avisa se a árvore filha que foi modificada ficou  
         // maior ou menor.  
  if (direction < 0) {  
      if (arvore->esq == NULL){  
    arvore->esq = arv_cria(registro);  
    // Ajustando balanceamento do nó criado e do nó atual.  
    arvore->esq->balanceamento = 0;  
    isTaller  = true;  
    arvore->balanceamento      = arvore->balanceamento - 1;  
      } else {  
    arvore->esq = arv_insere(arvore->esq, registro);  
    isTaller    = arvore->esq->sizeChanged;  
    if (isTaller) {  
      arvore->balanceamento    = arvore->balanceamento -1 ;  
    }  
      }  
  } else {  
      if (arvore->dir == NULL){  
    arvore->dir = arv_cria(registro);  
    // Ajustando balanceamento do nó criado e do nó atual.  
    arvore->dir->balanceamento = 0;  
    isTaller  = true;  
    arvore->balanceamento      = arvore->balanceamento + 1;  
      } else {
    arvore->dir = arv_insere(arvore->dir, registro);
    isTaller    = arvore->dir->sizeChanged;
    if (isTaller) {
      arvore->balanceamento      = arvore->balanceamento + 1;  
    }  
      }  
  }  
  // Nos veremos se geramos um balanceamento neste no da arvore. Se  
  // tivermos gerado, então balancearemos a árvore.  
  Arvore* nArvore = performRotations(arvore);  




if (isTaller && nArvore->balanceamento == 0) {  

    nArvore->sizeChanged = false;  

  } else {  

    nArvore->sizeChanged =  isTaller; 

  }  

  printf("SIZE CHANGED: %d \n" , nArvore->sizeChanged);  
  return nArvore;  
}
```

Neste código, o que faz o seguinte trecho?

```
if (isTaller && nArvore->balanceamento == 0) { 

    nArvore->sizeChanged = false;  

} else {  

    nArvore->sizeChanged =  isTaller; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código não é lá dos melhores, começando pela má identação (mas também não é dos piores). Olhando-se para o que ele faz, claramente é o procedimento de inserção em uma árvore auto-balanceada, provavelmente (mas não necessariamente) uma [árvore AVL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_AVL).

Bem, vamos começar tentando simplificar esse código:

```
if (isTaller && nArvore->balanceamento == 0) { 

    nArvore->sizeChanged = false;  

} else {  

    nArvore->sizeChanged =  isTaller; 

}
```

Em ambos os casos, alguma coisa é atribuída a `nArvore->sizeChanged`. Vamos montar uma tabela-verdade para saber o que será atribuído a `nArvore->sizeChanged`:

```
+----------+-----------------------------+----------------------+
| isTaller | nArvore->balanceamento == 0 | nArvore->sizeChanged |
+----------+-----------------------------+----------------------+
| true     | true                        | false                |
| true     | false                       | true                 |
| false    | true                        | false                |
| false    | false                       | false                |
+----------+-----------------------------+----------------------+
```

Ou seja, podemos substituir aquilo por isso:

```
nArvore->sizeChanged = isTaller && nArvore->balanceamento != 0;
```

O significado da variável `balanceamento` é algo que é claro quando você trabalha com árvores AVL e me parece estar implementado de forma correta (se mexer no nó esquerdo, pode ser que subtraia 1, mas se mexer no nó direito, pode ser que some 1). Já o caso do `isTaller` é um pouco mais obscuro, pelo nome deveria significar que a altura da árvore mudou, mas abaixo você verá que o nome da variável não reflete exatamente o seu significado.

A variável `isTaller` por padrão tem o valor `false`. Ela pode ficar verdadeira em quatro ocasiões:

- A) Quando `direction < 0` e `arvore->esq == NULL` - neste caso, o nó em questão no ponteiro `arvore` não tem filho esquerdo e passa a ter. Em seguida temos `arvore->balanceamento      = arvore->balanceamento - 1;`.
- B) Quando `direction >= 0` e `arvore->dir == NULL` - neste caso, o nó em questão no ponteiro `arvore` não tem filho direito e passa a ter. Em seguida temos `arvore->balanceamento      = arvore->balanceamento + 1;`.
- C) Quando `direction < 0`, `arvore->esq != NULL` e `arvore->esq->sizeChanged` - neste caso, temos também que `arvore->balanceamento    = arvore->balanceamento -1 ;`.
- D) Quando `direction >= 0`, `arvore->dir != NULL` e `arvore->dir->sizeChanged` - neste caso, temos também que `arvore->balanceamento      = arvore->balanceamento + 1;`.

Observe que isso significa que em todos os caminhos onde o `isTaller` torna-se verdadeiro, o `arvore->balanceamento` muda. E se o `isTaller` permanacer falso, o `arvore->balanceamento` ficará inalterado. Logo, essa variável indica se o balanceamento mudou, e um nome melhor para ela seria `balanceamentoMudou`.

Voltando então a isso:

```
nArvore->sizeChanged = isTaller && nArvore->balanceamento != 0;
```

Se renomearmos `isTaller` teremos isso:

```
nArvore->sizeChanged = balanceamentoMudou && nArvore->balanceamento != 0;
```

O que significa que `nArvore->sizeChanged` **será verdadeiro se o balanceamento do nó mudou e ainda assim continuou desbalanceado, sendo falso em caso contrário.** Isso explica a finalidade desse código que era o que você queria saber.

O nome `sizeChanged` não é adequado porque o significado desse campo não reflete isso. Um nome melhor seria `necessitaRebalanceamento`. Isso faz sentido quando essa variável é lida nos casos C e D, pois se o nó filho necessita de rebalanceamento, então o balanceamento do nó pai deve mudar, o que pode provocar a ocorrência de rotações para rebalancear.

Por fim, digo que usar `exit(1);` não é boa prática de programação, e são pouquíssimos os casos onde isso é a melhor coisa a se fazer. Entretanto, sem ver o contexto no qual a sua árvore é utilizada, fica difícil definir-se uma alternativa.

Comment: Perdão pela má elaboração da pergunta. Mas você respondeu perfeitamente o que eu gostaria de saber!

Comment: @PabloBorsone A sua pergunta não está mal-elaborada, ao menos não comparada com outras que são despejadas neste site todos os dias. Há espaço para melhorias no código postado, mas até que ele está razoável.

Comment: @PabloBorsone  Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não te restar mais nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no "✅" aqui do lado, o que também marca a sua pergunta como respondida/solucionada. Se por outro lado, ainda não estiver satisfeito, deixe um comentário e vamos esclarecer.

Comment: Pronto! Muito obrigado! :D